# g++ compiled exe file, will only run in Admin CMD, and not normal CMD

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, exe, access-denied

I'm using MinGW with Visual Studio Code. This is my first attempt to run CPP with VSCode.

I've configured my c_cpp_properties.json and tasks.json file to build my simple hello world file.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

The build runs fine with no errors, but when I try to execute the file on PowerShell or cmd as

```
a.exe
./a.exe
```

I get a "Access Denied" error.

But, if I open a Command Prompt(Admin) from the Win+X menu, and `cd` into my folder, and then run

```
a.exe
```

I get the output there correctly.

How do I give access rights to a normal user(I'm assuming that the cmd run normally, or the cmd run by VSCode is a user level cmd) so that he can execute the .exe files?

Note: The normal cmd can still compile the .cpp files