# access is denied in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I downloaded and installed vs code to run my C++ programs. When I try to run any program it is showing the following error:

```
Program 'Untitled-1.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:81
+ ...  ($?) { g++ Untitled-1.cpp -o Untitled-1 } ; if ($?) { .\Untitled-1 }
+                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:81
+ ...  ($?) { g++ Untitled-1.cpp -o Untitled-1 } ; if ($?) { .\Untitled-1 }
+                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: Please reformat the question and add some more details what you did and what you got.

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"hi";
}  i used this code. but when i run the code . i get the error message that i mentioned above

Comment: I still don't quite get the connection between "visual studio" (Microsoft?) and "g++" (GNU C compiler?).

Comment: @U.Windl Visual Studio Code is the IDE portion only - it doesn't come with a compiler (you configure that with tasks.json) so you can use it with any compiler you want.  Also, it is cross platform so it doesn't just run on Windows.

Comment: It has to be a configuration error.  You probably need to show us your tasks.json

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856041/vs-code-access-denied-when-executing-user-input-file-in-terminal and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888370/mingw-compiler-denying-access-to-files but neither of those have any answers either.

Comment: Where is Untitled-1.exe located on your disk?

Comment: This question offers a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933228/g-compiled-exe-file-will-only-run-in-admin-cmd-and-not-normal-cmd  If you start a command prompt with Run as Administrator then can you run the executable?

Answer (score 0):

the problem with this was, my antivirus mcafee software was stopping vs code to run program and make executable .exe files. to solve the problem you can exclude the files from being scanned.